# Can AI image generators be used as an aide to conceptual analysis?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, interpretation, experimental-philosophy

Within the last few months, AI image generators such as [craiyon](https://www.craiyon.com/) (the one I've been using) have proliferated and then been used to generate all sorts of sometimes funny, sometimes compelling imagery. Usually, if my input is fairly "abstract" (or: consists substantially in words like *logic*, *theory*, *inference*, etc.) the output seems to be pastiches of diagrams and graphs the AI scanned while evaluating the input. Not particularly "informative," then.

Or for example, then, I just tried out *knowledge* by itself and the AI put out pictures of a bald-head outline with a menagerie of symbol-like thought-bubbles inside. I followed up with *knowledge gettier* and the output was pictures of assortments of books (or things that look like books). Next I tried *understanding* and the results were not especially dissimilar to those for *knowledge* (although now the outlined bald head had some brain-like characteristics intertwined with the symbols/thought-bubbles). Jarringly, *episteme* mapped to pictures of butterflies; *epistemology* gave blurry portraitures resembling drawings of Socrates (or some generic bearded philosopher, anyway).

So still, not quite much, if anything, in the way of showing what parts the relevant concepts might "break down into," but still showing what kinds of intuitive associations or contrasts there are between terms for those concepts.

If comparing the outputs for such terms can "help" with conceptual analysis, I would think of the process as something akin to using [computer proofs in mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-nondeductive/#ComPro) or [experimental philosophy more broadly](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/experimental-philosophy/). **If computer proofs are admissible in mathematics, and if experimental philosophy is not a "dead end" (so to speak), then does justification for those transfer over to using AI to complement conceptual analysis?**

Comment: The craiyon thing you link to is quite primitive. You won't get much help in conceptual analysis from that.

Comment: @BillOnne, yeah, I see results from other programs that look way better (even just as pictures), but a lot of the programs seem to be of the register-and/or-pay variety. I'm not averse to registration/payment except that I'm being lazy about it for now, so I'm just sticking with craiyon until I snap out of my "depression" or whatever.

Comment: Certainly it could help if it can provide more vivid and empirical images than dictionaries in a short duration for extensions of those impure and pure sensuous concepts in the sense of Kantian epistemology. But its effect must be limited per Kant since the end result here is just images not rules…